Cloud functions for updating existing data
I am doing an app in flutter and I try to update for services the information that the user already introduced before (edit) . Right now when I rename it appears that is successfuly edited but the information still not change, I used cloud functions for this but still not working, even if I receive a message that it worked.
this is my index.js
const {onDocumentCreated} = require("firebase-functions/v2/firestore");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const serviceAccount = require("./serviceAccountKey.json");
const functions = require("firebase-functions");

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL:
    "https://animo-f15e0-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app",
});

exports.sendChatNotification = onDocumentCreated(
    {
      document: "notifications/{notificationId}",
      cpu: 2,
    },
    async (event) => {
      const snap = event.data;
      const notification = snap.data();

      const message = {
        token: notification.token,
        notification: {
          title: notification.title,
          body: notification.body,
        },
        data: notification.data,
        apns: {
          headers: {
            "apns-push-type": "alert",
          },
          payload: {
            aps: {
              sound: "default",
            },
          },
        },
      };

      try {
        const response = await admin.messaging().send(message);
        console.log("Successfully sent notification:", response);
        await snap.ref.delete();
        return {success: true};
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error sending notification:", error);
        return {error};
      }
    },
);

exports.addChatMessage = functions.https.onCall(async (request) => {
  try {
    const {message, sender, name, chatRoomId, rid} = request.data;

    console.log("Received data:");
    console.log("message: ", request.data.message);
    console.log("sender: ", request.data.sender);
    console.log("time: ", request.data.time);
    console.log("type: ", request.data.type);
    console.log("unread: ", request.data.unread);
    console.log("name: ", request.data.name);
    console.log("chatRoomId: ", request.data.chatRoomId);
    console.log("rid: ", request.data.rid);

    const batch = admin.firestore().batch();
    const messageColl = admin.firestore().collection("ChatRoom");

    batch.set(messageColl.doc(chatRoomId).collection("chats").doc(), {
      "sender": sender,
      "time": admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
      "type": "text",
      "message": message,
      "unread": true,
      "name": name,
    });

    const recipientDoc = await admin.firestore().collection("Users")
        .doc(rid).get();
    const recipientToken = recipientDoc.data() ? recipientDoc.data()
        .fcmToken : null;

    if (recipientToken) {
      batch.set(admin.firestore().collection("notifications").doc(), {
        "token": recipientToken,
        "title": name,
        "body": message,
        "data": {"chatRoomId": chatRoomId, "type": "chat_message"},
        "timestamp": admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
      });
    }

    await batch.commit();
    return {success: true};
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error adding chat message: ", error);
    return {success: false, error: error.message};
  }
});

exports.updateUserData = functions.https.onCall(async (request) => {
  try {
    const {
      uid,
      data,
      business,
      social,
      service,
      product,
      review,
      booking,
      order,
      addingNewService,
      addingNewProduct,
      addingNewReview,
      addingNewBooking,
      placingNewOrder,
    } = request.data;

    console.log("User id: ", uid);
    const userDoc = admin.firestore().collection("Users").doc(uid);

    if (data) {
      await userDoc.update(data);
    }

    if (business) {
      console.log("Business data: ", business);
      await userDoc
          .collection("BusinessAccount")
          .doc("detail")
          .set(business, {merge: true});
    }

    if (social) {
      console.log("Social data: ", social);
      await userDoc
          .collection("Social")
          .doc("detail")
          .set(social, {merge: true});
    }

    if (service) {
      console.log("Service data: ", service);
      if (addingNewService === true) {
        service.createdAt = admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp();
        await userDoc.collection("Services").add(service);
      } else if (service.serviceId) {
        const serviceId = service.serviceId;
        service.updatedAt = admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp();
        delete service.serviceId;
        await userDoc
            .collection("Services")
            .doc(serviceId)
            .update(service);
      }
    }

    if (booking && addingNewBooking === true) {
      booking.createdAt = admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp();
      console.log("Booking data: ", booking);

      await admin.firestore()
          .collection("ChatRoom")
          .doc(booking.chatRoomId)
          .collection("chats")
          .doc(booking.docId)
          .set({
            ...booking,
            time: admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
          });

      await admin.firestore()
          .collection("Users")
          .doc(booking.sender)
          .collection("Bookings")
          .add({
            ...booking,
            createdAt: admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
          });

      await admin.firestore()
          .collection("Users")
          .doc(booking.serviceProviderId)
          .collection("Bookings")
          .add({
            ...booking,
            createdAt: admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
          });
    }

    if (product && addingNewProduct === true) {
      product.createdAt = admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp();
      console.log("Product data: ", product);
      await userDoc.collection("Products").add(product);
    }

    if (review && addingNewReview === true) {
      review.timestamp = admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp();
      console.log("Review data: ", review);
      const reviewRef = admin.firestore()
          .collection("Users")
          .doc(review.serviceProviderId)
          .collection("BusinessAccount")
          .doc("detail")
          .collection("reviews");
      await reviewRef.add(review);
    }

    if (order && placingNewOrder === true) {
      order.createdAt = admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp();
      console.log("Order data: ", order);

      const orderId = admin.firestore().collection("orders").doc().id;
      order.orderId = orderId;

      await admin.firestore()
          .collection("Users")
          .doc(order.sellerId)
          .collection("Orders")
          .doc(orderId)
          .set({
            ...order,
            createdAt: admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
          });

      await admin.firestore()
          .collection("Users")
          .doc(order.buyerId)
          .collection("Orders")
          .doc(orderId)
          .set({
            ...order,
            createdAt: admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
          });

      const sellerDoc = await admin.firestore()
          .collection("Users")
          .doc(order.sellerId)
          .get();

      const sellerData = sellerDoc.data();
      const sellerToken = sellerData ? sellerData.fcmToken : null;

      if (sellerToken) {
        await admin.firestore().collection("notifications").add({
          token: sellerToken,
          title: "New Order",
          body: `New order received for ${order.productName}`,
          data: {
            type: "new_order",
            orderId: orderId,
            productId: order.productId,
          },
          timestamp: admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
        });
      }

      return {success: true, orderId: orderId};
    }

    return {success: true};
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error updating user data: ", error);
    return {success: false, error: error.message};
  }
});

exports.onNewBookingRequest = onDocumentCreated(
    {
      document: "notifications/{notificationId}",
      cpu: 2,
    },
    async (event) => {
      const snap = event.data;
      const notification = snap.data();

      if (notification.type !== "booking_request") {
        return;
      }

      try {
        // Get recipient's FCM token
        const recipientDoc = await admin.firestore()
            .collection("Users")
            .doc(notification.recipientId)
            .get();

        const recipientData = recipientDoc.data();
        const recipientToken = recipientData ? recipientData.fcmToken : null;

        if (!recipientToken) {
          console.log("No FCM token found for recipient");
          return;
        }

        // Send FCM notification
        await admin.messaging().send({
          token: recipientToken,
          notification: {
            title: notification.title,
            body: notification.body,
          },
          data: {
            chatRoomId: notification.data.chatRoomId,
            bookingId: notification.data.bookingId,
            click_action: "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK",
          },
        });

        console.log("Notification sent successfully");

        // Clean up the notification document after sending
        await snap.ref.delete();
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error sending notification:", error);
      }
    },
);

exports.onNewOrder = onDocumentCreated(
    {
      document: "notifications/{notificationId}",
      cpu: 2,
    },
    async (event) => {
      const snap = event.data;
      const notification = snap.data();

      if (notification.type !== "new_order") {
        return;
      }

      try {
        // Get recipient's FCM token
        const recipientDoc = await admin.firestore()
            .collection("Users")
            .doc(notification.recipientId)
            .get();

        const recipientData = recipientDoc.data();
        const recipientToken = recipientData ? recipientData.fcmToken : null;

        if (!recipientToken) {
          console.log("No FCM token found for recipient");
          return;
        }

        // Send FCM notification
        await admin.messaging().send({
          token: recipientToken,
          notification: {
            title: notification.title,
            body: notification.body,
          },
          data: {
            orderId: notification.data.orderId,
            productId: notification.data.productId,
            type: "new_order",
            click_action: "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK",
          },
        });

        console.log("Order notification sent successfully");

        // Clean up the notification document after sending
        await snap.ref.delete();
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error sending order notification:", error);
      }
    },
);

and
void _editService(BuildContext context, String serviceId, Map<String, dynamic> currentData) {
    // Initialize controllers with current data
    final TextEditingController nameController = TextEditingController(text: currentData['name']);
    final TextEditingController descriptionController = TextEditingController(text: currentData['description']);
    final TextEditingController priceController = TextEditingController(text: currentData['price'].toString());

    showModalBottomSheet(
      context: context,
      isScrollControlled: true,
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(top: Radius.circular(20)),
      ),
      builder: (BuildContext bottomSheetContext) {
        return Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(
            bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom,
            left: 16,
            right: 16,
            top: 16,
          ),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: <Widget>[
              TextField(
                controller: nameController,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  labelText: "Service Name",
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 16),
              TextField(
                controller: descriptionController,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  labelText: "Description",
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 16),
              TextField(
                controller: priceController,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  labelText: "Price",
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                  prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.attach_money),
                ),
                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 24),
              ElevatedButton(
                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                  backgroundColor: darkBlueColor,
                  foregroundColor: Colors.white,
                  minimumSize: const Size(double.infinity, 50),
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                  ),
                ),
                onPressed: () async {
                  try {
                    showDialog(
                      context: bottomSheetContext,
                      barrierDismissible: false,
                      builder: (BuildContext dialogContext) {
                        return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                      },
                    );

                    AppCloudFunctionService appCloudFunctionService = AppCloudFunctionService();
                    final result = await appCloudFunctionService.updateUserData({
                      'uid': userId,
                      'service': {
                        'serviceId': serviceId,
                        'name': nameController.text.trim(),
                        'description': descriptionController.text.trim(),
                        'price': double.parse(priceController.text),
                        'photoUrl': currentData['photoUrl'],
                      },
                    });

                    if (!result) {
                      throw Exception('Failed to update service');
                    }

                    if (bottomSheetContext.mounted) {
                      Navigator.pop(bottomSheetContext); // Close loading dialog
                      Navigator.pop(bottomSheetContext); // Close bottom sheet
                    }

                    if (context.mounted) {
                      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                        const SnackBar(
                          content: Text('Service updated successfully'),
                          backgroundColor: Colors.green,
                        ),
                      );
                    }
                  } catch (e) {
                    print('Error updating service: $e');
                    if (context.mounted) {
                      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                        SnackBar(
                          content: Text('Error updating service: $e'),
                          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                        ),
                      );
                    }
                  }
                },
                child: const Text(
                  'Save Changes',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  void _deleteService(String serviceId) async {
    try {
      // Show confirmation dialog
      bool confirmDelete = await showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            title: const Text('Delete Service'),
            content: const Text('Are you sure you want to delete this service?'),
            actions: [
              TextButton(
                onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(false),
                child: const Text('Cancel'),
              ),
              TextButton(
                onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(true),
                child: const Text(
                  'Delete',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
      );

      if (confirmDelete == true) {
        AppCloudFunctionService appCloudFunctionService = AppCloudFunctionService();
        final result = await appCloudFunctionService.updateUserData({
          'uid': userId,
          'service': {
            'serviceId': serviceId,
            'delete': true,
          },
        });

        if (!result) {
          throw Exception('Failed to delete service');
        }

        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
          const SnackBar(
            content: Text('Service deleted successfully'),
            backgroundColor: Colors.green,
          ),
        );
      }
    } catch (error) {
      print('Failed to delete service: $error');
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(
          content: Text('Error deleting service: $error'),
          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        ),
      );
    }
  }

